# How can we disable Open-telemetry default metrics ex JVM

Tags: java, jvm, open-telemetry

We want to get only custom metrics from open-telemetry, but right now we are getting the default metrics as well related to JVM which we dont want.

How can we disable the JVM related metrics in open-telemetry?

We are getting like below which we want to disable :
HELP process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage Measure of memory used
TYPE process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage gauge
process_runtime_jvm_memory_usage{job="test",pool="CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'",type="non_heap"} 1.282176e+06

Comment: If you are using javaagent you can try with setting `otel.instrumentation.runtime-metrics.enabled` flag to false.

Ref: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/instrumentation/runtime-metrics/javaagent/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/instrumentation/javaagent/runtimemetrics/RuntimeMetricsInstaller.java

Comment: How did you manage to get JVM metrics by default? I don't get them on the contrary! (Not using the javaagent)

Comment: @GaëlJ we are using openTelemetry Java Agent which send JVM Metrics by default to the Metrics Endpoint